# Troubleshooting "access is denied" error when running cgminer

Tags: litecoin

I am trying to run cgminer on Windows 7.  However every time I execute the command:

```
cgminer --scrypt -o http://coinotron.com:3334 -u username -p pass  --thread-concurrency 8192 -I 10 -g 1 -w 256
```

It says `access is denied`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the part "-u username -p pass" with the actual username and password of your worker.
Log into coinotron and create a new worker in the "Add Worker" section. The worker will appear in the table below. Use the displayed name and password of your worker in the command and you should be fine.

Comment: Thats precisely what I did. I didnt want to put the username and password so I subsituted it in the post

Comment: It was an antivirus issue. It finallly worked

Comment: Processes that use a lot of system resources are sometimes blocked by antivirus software, because sometimes adware mines bitcoins on the computer of its victim.